# Java Regex for file path validation

Tags: java, regex, string

I need to come up with a regex according to these rules.
It is guaranteed that path is either a correct path, or it has some of the following errors:

More than one ~

~ is not at the start

~ mixed with \ (~ in Windows path)

More than one C:

C: is not at the start

C: mixed with / (C: in Unix path)

\ mixed with /

Illegal paths example:

/folder1/folder2\folder3

C:\User/root

/dev/~/

C:/a/b/c/d

~\folder

~/~

~~

C:\Folder\Subfolder\C:\

So far i used "([A-Z|a-z]:|~|/|\\[^*|"<>?\n]*)|(\\\\.*?\\.*)" and "([a-zA-Z]:)?(\\[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+)+\\?"

its a method that accepts String path and boolean toWin(if we need to convert unix path to windows). /////////// What i need to do --> Method signature: public static String convertPath(String path, boolean toWin) Convert path to Unix\Windows path depending on a boolean parameter. Unix path may start with ~ or /. Every subdirectory must end with / character except the last one. . and .. refer to current directory and parent directory. Filename doesn't necessarily have the extension. // i managed to solve it, but cant come up with a regex to validate path

I would really appreciate some help. Thanks.

Comment: Are you extracting or validating?

Comment: If you are just validating, you can simply use `Files.exists(path)`. Note: it just checks if path exist (does not guarrantee that it is possible). You can either try creating a directory there and removing. If it does not gives error. the path is valid.

Comment: Can you please figure out why the path "C:/a/b/c/d"  is invalid?

Comment: @MonkeyZeus its a method that accepts String path and boolean toWin(if we need to convert unix path to windows). 

/////////// What i need to do -->
Method signature:

public static String convertPath(String path, boolean toWin)
Convert path to Unix\Windows path depending on a boolean parameter.

Unix path may start with ~ or /. Every subdirectory must end with / character except the last one. . and .. refer to current directory and parent directory. Filename doesn't necessarily have the extension.
// i managed to solve it, but cant come up with a regex to validate path

Comment: @MuhammadKhuzaimaUmair thanks. It's something new for me!
However i need to check String path, not file(

Comment: @icarus it also validates the directory (not only files). the parameter `path` here is type of `String`

Comment: @MuhammadKhuzaimaUmair yeah, i got it. But i need to solve the problem using regex(

Comment: Was my answer helpful to you? Consider voting.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
 (?=(?:.*~){2,}).*$        #More than one ~
|(?=.*~)^(?!~).+$          #~ is not at the start
|(?=.*~)(?=.*\\).+$        #~ mixed with \ (~ in Windows path)
|(?=(?:.*[Cc]:){2,}).*$    #More than one C:
|(?=.*[Cc]:)^(?![Cc]:).+$  #C: is not at the start
|(?=.*[Cc]:)(?=.*\/).*$    #C: OR \ mixed with /
|(?=.*\\)(?=.*\/).*$       #\ mixed with /
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/xGJmWQ/1)

Comment: You can obviously optimize this and make it more concise but I opted for clarity first.